# Why image not served directly from cache when they are not expired?

Tags: google-chrome, http, caching

I have a static image which will expire in 9 minutes.
It has following headers set by the server:

Cache-control: max0age=523 
Expires: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 23:28:14 GMT (in 5 minutes)
Last-Modified:Wed, 12 Nov 2014 08:06:06 GMT

When I refresh the page browser makes request to server instead of serving it from the cache. As expected it gets 304 from server.
Screenshot from Chrome dev tools below: 
[image]

I compared it with resource cached with same headers (max-age and last-modified) and seeing that content gets served directly from cache:

[image]

So basically I have two questions:

1. Why Chrome does not serve image from cache and validates it against server?
2. Why same not applies to my second example with js file from Bing.com and it served directly from cache? Is it because "public" specified in cache-control or aggressive expiration date?

Some clarifications:

1. I'm refreshing the page in both examples.
2. I am not doing hard refresh (Crtl+R or Ctrl+F5).
3. It is not because of dev tools opened, I tried to close dev tools and I'm seeing same in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is sending a `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header.  That's means your browser is deliberately bypassing the cache when you refresh.

- If navigate to the page normally instead of refreshing, it should load the image from the cache.
- If you hold Shift when you click Refresh, you'll force a hard refresh, which additionally won't since an `If-Modified-Since` header.  You'll get a 200 instead of a 304, without any caching.

Comment: thanks, but that does not explain it. 1. I'm refreshing the page in both examples, so that is not the case. 2. I am not doing hard refresh.

Comment: @VitaliyGanzha A soft refresh isn't necessarily going to behave the same on every site.  Chrome uses many factors to decide what it should keep and what it should reload.  Sometimes I'll attempt to soft refresh and end up with a hard refresh instead for seemingly no reason.  I think it's a safe bet that Chrome is much more likely to re-request a localhost resource.

Comment: Yes, I would like to find out why it is happening because IE does the same. It seems to me that max-age is very short, but I want to confirm that

Comment: If you mean `max-age=231`, that's coming from your server.

Comment: Yes, I know that, what I don't know if this is causing hitting server for image validation or something else.

Comment: @VitaliyGanzha It's hitting the server because you're refreshing and it's decided it can efficiently check whether the image has been updated without slowing down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your settings in developer tools?

[image: Disable cache checkbox in developer tools]

There is a checkbox to disable cache. I was having the same problem and the checkbox was checked (I don't why). It is a small checkbox, I spend hours until see it. After I unchecked it, cache was working just [fine in my website](https://mtg.cardsrealm.com/card/).